# dojo.widget.byId not working with Internet Explorer 9 or below

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, struts2, dojo

Below javaScript is failing while running In IE 9 or below.

```
function setSelectedIndex() {


var s=dojo.widget.byId('vendor_name');

v=document.getElementById('vName').value;

s.setValue(v);

}
```

Here I want to set the vendorname to a default value from a hidden variable. My jsp code is below.

```
<tr>
<td width="150" colspan="5"><b><s:label value="Vendor Name"     id="vendor_nameLabel"> </s:label></b> <s:hidden name="vendorName" id="vName"></s:hidden></td>
<td width="300" colspan="7"> <sx:autocompleter list="vendorNameList" name="vendor_name" autoComplete="false" id="vendor_name"/></td>
</tr>
```

This script is working fine in firefox , chrome and IE 11 but it is failing in IE 9.

I am using struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.6. IN IE 9 it gives me error.

Comment: Its an enhancement, I can not change library files or any plugins

Comment: The long-deprecated S2 Dojo Plugin uses a very old version of Dojo (0.4.x, IIRC). You'll need to dig out the old Dojo docs and/or source and see if you can track down the issue.